# How to create an asyncio task that return value?

Tags: python, async-await, return, python-asyncio, telethon

I'm figuring out how to return a list[] in `asyncio`
I know `asyncio.gather` could help me but there are so many ways I'm now confused.
How Do I return value from main() ? Thank

```
async def wait_until(dt):
    # sleep until the specified datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    await asyncio.sleep((dt - now).total_seconds())

async def run_at(dt, coro):
    await wait_until(dt)
    return await coro

async def main():
    test=[]
    async for message in client.iter_messages(channel):
        test.append(message)
        return test


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(run_at(datetime(2020, 12, 29, 19, 17),main()))
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[main()]))
# How to get test[] or How to pass it to another task?
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: I'll use a global var, but I'm sure there is a better method to do it. Also, are you aware that you returning `test[]` after the first loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=gather#asyncio.gather) documentation:

> If all awaitables are completed successfully, the result is an aggregate list of returned values. The order of result values corresponds to the order of awaitables in aws.

From the [`asyncio.loop.run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) documentation:

> Return the Future’s result or raise its exception.

So `gather` is an `async def` that returns all the results passed, and `run_until_complete` runs the loop "converting" the awaitable into the result. Basically, the return values are passed through:

```py
results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[main()]))
tests = results[0]
```

Note that `gather` with just one item is redundant, as it's equivalent to just using that one item:

```py
tests = loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

If you want to communicate two independent tasks without using global variables, you probably want to use an [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html), and give the same queue instance to both `async def` as input parameters. One will [`put`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.put) "messages", and the other will [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.get) them.

You can combine this with `wait`, `gather`, `create_task`, etc. to pretty much do everything you need.